# LDAP not returning users for query of Users or Domain Users

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap

I'm doing an LDAP query using C# and the DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher class. But, the same holds true of raw queries using the LDP tool that comes with Windows.

I present the user of my program to say during the installer that users from "X" group should have their LDAP information transmitted (display name, email, account name, objectguid) to a management tool. The tool gives the user a list of groups and then saves the group selected in the registry for later use.  For whatever group is selected, I want to query for all enabled users in the group.

If I create a group and add users, when I query for users, all in the group are returned. If I put a user in Group 1, create a Group 2 and put Group 1 in Group 2, then when I query for users, the user in Group 1 is returned. It works.

The problem is when they select just the Users group or the Domain Users group. When I use those to query for users, zero users are returned. If I look in AD management tools, of course all users are in Domain Users or Users.

```
public IList<UserInfo> GetGroupUsers(string dn)
{
    var users = new List<UserInfo>();

    using (var de = new DirectoryEntry(RootDomainName))
    {
        using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(de))
        {
            string filter = $"(&(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={dn})(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))";
            searcher.Filter = filter;

            searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(DISTINGUISHEDNAME_PROP);
            searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(SAMACCOUNTNAME_PROP);
            searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(MAIL_PROP);
            searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(DISPLAYNAME_PROP);
            searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(OBJECTGUID_PROP);

            SearchResultCollection AllResults = searcher.FindAll();
            //MessageBox.Show($"Filter: {filter}\r\nResult count: {AllResults.Count}");
            foreach (SearchResult sr in AllResults)
            {
                var userInfo = new UserInfo()
                {
                    DisplayName = sr.GetProperty(DISPLAYNAME_PROP),
                    DistinguishedName = sr.GetProperty(DISTINGUISHEDNAME_PROP),
                    Account = sr.GetProperty(SAMACCOUNTNAME_PROP),
                    Mail = sr.GetProperty(MAIL_PROP),
                    Guid = new Guid((byte[]) sr.Properties[OBJECTGUID_PROP][0]),
                    Path = sr.Path
                };
                users.Add(userInfo);
            }
        }
    }

    return users;
}
```

Most of the magic (poison) sauce is in the filter which I gleaned from other articles: `string filter = $"(&(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={dn})(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))";`

Is there any way to tweak my query, or is this a known issue, or do I just have to be smarter about the Domain User or User groups?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with the query itself, its to do with the way Domain Users is allocated.  Normally the Domain Users group doesn't have any members.  The users get this group included in their access token via the primaryGroupID attribute.

The primaryGroupID contains the RID portion of the SID Domain Users group, with this example of a SID S-1-5-21-1640481606-4090368528-1002570995-513, it contains 513.

Gary.